# Is there any API for reading all subscriber emails from feedburner

Tags: google-api, feedburner

Is there any API for **reading all emails from feedburner subscribers**. I want to check remotely using an API without downloading **CSV** file. ( or if any other way )

Thank You.

```
Update:
```

I am reading email from CSV file and i am sending emails to all verified emails everyday after downloading the CSV file from feedburner. So new users has to wait until i download a newly updated CSV and again run my php script to send emails. So it getting delay.

So how can i check emails without downloading CSV file from feedburner and send a email instantly.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only APIs available are:

- the FeedFlare API, and
- the Awareness API.

Neither allow you to query your subscriber list.

http://code.google.com/apis/feedburner/developers_guide.html

Maybe you can try to automate the procedure of downloading the CSV. Possibly with something like Selenium?

Then you could download it at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

No feedburner is not providing such type of API.